# The image under transformations

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the family of circles $
{x}^{2}
$
+ $
{y}^{2}
$  =by
under the transformation $
\mathit{\zeta}\mathrm{{=}}\raise0.7ex\hbox{${1}$}\!\!\left/{}\right.\!\!\lower0.7ex\hbox{${z}$}
$

Comment: You are missing a RHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R>0$ and $C=\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|=R\}$ and $f(z)=1/z$.

If $z \in C$, then $|f(z)|=\frac{1}{|z|}=\frac{1}{R}$. Hence

$$f(C)=\{\zeta \in \mathbb C: |\zeta|=1/R\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

You family is

$$zz^*=,$$ and becomes

$$\frac1{\zeta\zeta^*}=\frac1{\xi^2+\upsilon^2}=.$$

Comment: Is this stereographic projection

Comment: Of the Riemann sphere

Comment: There is no sphere here.